# AutoCompleteTextView on Filtering one to one not working

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

Hi I am using two `autoCompleteTextView` STATE and CITY. Here CITY filtered and shows according to the state selected. But when I save the text and come from onResume. 
Here I face a problem like if the STATE is changed then without CITY it accepts the value which it should not. Here is my code:

```
//state
actv_state.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long rowId) {
ld_state = actv_state.getText().toString();
cityarray = mDbHelper.getCity(ld_state);
ArrayAdapter<String> mp_city_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
CreateLead.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,cityarray);
actv_city.setThreshold(1);
actv_city.setAdapter(mp_city_adapter);
//city
actv_city.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
int arg2, long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ld_city = actv_city.getText().toString();
}});}});

//
actv_state.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
int count) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
int after) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ld_state = actv_state.getText().toString();
for (int i = 0; i < statearray.size(); i++) {
if (ld_state.equals(statearray.get(i))) {
count = 1;
break;
} else {
count = 0;
}
}

// city
actv_city.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
int count) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
int after) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ld_state = actv_state.getText().toString();
ld_city = actv_city.getText().toString();
cityarray = mDbHelper.getCity(ld_state);
for (int i = 0; i < cityarray.size(); i++) {
if (ld_city.equals(cityarray.get(i))) {
ccount = 1;
break;
} else {
ccount = 0;
}
}
}
});
```

Comment: I got the answer by making actv_city.setText("").before getting string of state